# How to modify pipe to return custom response?

Tags: node.js, request, pipe

How can I return a custom response (or error) to the client side with `request` library? The `.pipe()` will always pipe the original response back to the client

This returns the original response

```
request(options)
    .on('error', err => {
      return cb(err);
    })
    .on('response', response => {
      // This is an error
      if (response.statusCode === 500) {
        const error = new Error('File not found');
        return cb(error);
      }
      return cb(null, response, 'application/pdf');
    })
    .pipe(res);
```

This returns my custom response

```
request(options)
    .on('error', err => {
      return cb(err);
    })
    .on('response', response => {
      // This is an error
      if (response.statusCode === 500) {
        const error = new Error('File not found');
        return cb(error);
      }
      return cb(null, response, 'application/pdf');
    });
    // .pipe(res);
```

Is it possible to control whether not to pipe it based on the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request will start piping as soon as it receives a response. If you want to control piping or not based on the status code you receive, you'll have to make the pipe call on the response callback like this:

```
const req = request(options)
  .on('error', err => cb(err))
  .on('response', response => {
    // This is an error
    if (response.statusCode === 500) {
      const error = new Error('File not found');
      return cb(error);
    }

    if (typeof response.end === 'function') {
      req.pipe(response);
    }
    if (response.req.finished) {
      return cb(null, response, 'application/pdf');
    }
  });
```

Comment: it gave me an `Error
500 You cannot pipe after data has been emitted from the response.
Error: You cannot pipe after data has been emitted from the response.`

Comment: I've just fixed the code, it was `res` (the outer response object) instead of `response`.

Comment: This will pipe the response of the request you make to the `res` stream. Watch out, if your `cb` callback emits data to the `res` stream as well you'll probably get the same error.

Comment: Sorry the error occurred when I do `req.pipe(res)`. It works fine for `req.pipe(response)` except we have put a `req.end();` in the error handler before callback. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I just realized it is not exactly working: It gave me the error if I pipe it on('response') - `internal/streams/legacy.js:44
    dest.end();
         ^

TypeError: dest.end is not a function
    at Request.onend (internal/streams/legacy.js:44:10)`

What should I do?

Comment: I have updated your answer to the working code. please review it and I'll set it as the answer. Thanks again @Augusto!

Comment: You can change the second `if (typeof …) { … }` statement simply to `req.pipe(response, { end: !!response.end })`

Answer (score 2):

Once you've read from the stream, that data won't be piped somewhere else, so you can't read the first part of the content, then decide you want to pipe the whole thing and then call `.pipe()` and expect the original content that you already read to be in the piped response.

You could perhaps read some content, keep track of exactly what you read and then if you decide you just want to pipe it, you could then send what you've already read and the call `.pipe()`.  You'd have to test it yourself to see if there are any race conditions that might cause you to lose some data.

If the data is not large, a relatively easy thing to do would be to read all the data (the `request()` library can be used in a mode that will just get all the response for you) and then once you have all the data, you could examine the data and decide what to send.  You could either send the original data or you could modify it and send the modified data or you could just decide to send something different in its place.

Comment: makes total sense! I tried to use `async/await` to collect the response but it is not working.. can you help to give a simple example in doing so?

Comment: @JeeMok - As always here, it's very difficult to help with code we can't see so to have any chance at helping you with your code, you'd have to add it to your question so we could see what you're trying to do.